# Generic DAO throwing ClassCastException

Tags: hibernate

I have a GenericDAO class, which is extended by all my type specific DAO. This generic DAO  class has below method and it works fine.

```
protected List<T> findByCriteria(Criterion... criterion) {
    Criteria crit = getSession().createCriteria(getPersistentClass());
    for (Criterion c : criterion) {
        crit.add(c);
    }
    return crit.list();
}
```

Now, all I did is add another more method with more parameters, but it throws me exception "java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.String; cannot be cast to java.lang.String". Below is the method signature.

```
 public List<T> getByCriteria(int iPage, int iCount, Order order, ProjectionList pl, Criterion... criteria){
    Criteria crit = getSession().createCriteria(getPersistentClass());
    for (Criterion c : criteria) {
         crit.add(c);
    }
    // set max results to return
    //crit.setMaxResults(iCount);
    // set first record in result starting from
    //crit.setFirstResult((iPage-1)*iCount);
    //crit.list();  // Doesn't matter even if I just put it one line above without assign
    return crit.list();   //This is the line which throws exception
}
```

What I was trying is add more filter criteria to the search function, but because of the exception I commented out the additional code and am just imitating the working function findByCriteria. I search across the net, but couldn't figure out how to fix this or how come the first method is working fine and the second one throws error. Even the hibernate query generated by the two are same.

**UPDATE:**
Below is the exception stack trace:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.String; cannot be cast to java.lang.String
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.StringTypeDescriptor.unwrap(StringTypeDescriptor.java:39)
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.VarcharTypeDescriptor$1.doBind(VarcharTypeDescriptor.java:57)
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind(BasicBinder.java:93)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:280)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:275)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.bindPositionalParameters(Loader.java:1969)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.bindParameterValues(Loader.java:1940)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1875)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1836)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1816)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:900)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:342)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2526)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2512)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2342)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2337)
at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:124)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1662)
at org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:374)
at com.felees.hbnpojogen.persistence.impl.GenericHibernateDaoImpl.getByCriteria(GenericHibernateDaoImpl.java:288)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy44.getByCriteria(Unknown Source)
at com.wipro.wcc.services.data.DataLayerWccarchiveImpl.executeCriteria(DataLayerWccarchiveImpl.java:510)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy37.executeCriteria(Unknown Source)
at com.wipro.wcc.controller.DocumentController.search(DocumentController.java:112)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:214)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:748)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:931)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:833)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:807)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1008)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Regards,

Pankaj

Comment: And the stack trace of the exception is...

Answer (score 1):

A silly mistake on my side. While preparing the criteria array, has passed string array instead of the value against like,lt,eq etc, that was causing the issue. Don't know how I overlooked that.